# Exclude ip address from nginx limits

Tags: nginx

I would like to exclude 1 static ip address "217.55.190.187" from nginx limits
I tried installing geo module but it didn't work

```
geo $limited_ip {
default      1;
217.55.190.187  0;
}

map $limited_ip $limited_ip_key {
    0 '';
    1 $binary_remote_addr;
}
        limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=wafd1:10m   rate=10r/s;
        limit_req   zone=wafd1 burst=40 nodelay;

        limit_conn_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=wafd:10m;
        limit_conn   wafd 15;
```

and still got errors:

2013/12/30 20:48:37 [error] 12550#0: *4646 limiting requests, excess: 40.080 by zone"wafd1", client: 217.55.190.187, server: alwafd.

I think it can be done by if statement

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this solve your problem - http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,211989,211990 ? (3rd result for "nginx limit_req by ip")

Answer (score 1):

you must use defined $limited_ip_key as key:

```
limit_req_zone  $limited_ip_key  zone=wafd1:10m   rate=10r/s;
```